# how to export survey results in csv without html in qualtrics?

Tags: html, qualtrics

I have created a survey where some of the questions include html and css to format text.
The problem I am facing is when i export the data in csv format, the headers include the html and css I have written in question source.
Is there any way I can pull the data excluding html and css?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy alternative is to remove all html tags after download. Assuming you are using a recent version of excel to edit the file, you can do a find and replace for all html tags to help clean up the data.

Simply replace "<*>" with "" excluding the quotation marks. It's helpful in cleaning the file of unnecessary html.

Comment: hmm.. I am aware of the workaround.. Was wondering if there are available options in qualtrics to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to remove it is to edit the survey.

For question text, click on the question text then 'Edit Question Label' at the bottom of the input box. Remove the html there.

For choices/answers, click on Tools (gear icon), then Recode and check Variable Names and Question Export Tags (if applicable).  Remove the html.

Answer (score 0):

T. Gibbons is correct in that there is not a way to do this besides editing the survey.

If you want to remove all of the HTML tags without going through each question and answer, there is a tool called ["strip formatting..."](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/survey-tools/survey-tools-overview/) that is available in the Survey Tools dropdown. This will remove all HTML tags from your survey but also removes all text formatting (bold, italics, color, font, size, etc) so only use it if you are ok with stripping out all text styling as well as images or any other content in the survey.

Comment: Ok John. I will check this